# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value(When adding to a array)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, optional-values

I have some code that receives value from a segue and replaces a certain element of an array with the index number that I have.

The initialization of the variables is:

```
var noteTitles: [String] = ["Sample Note"]
var noteBodies: [String] = ["This is what lies within"]
var selectedNoteIndex: Int!
var newTitle: String!
var newBody: String!
```

and I have a segue that makes the last 3 values the values that I want them to be.

under viewDidLoad(), I have this:

```
    if newTitle == nil && newBody == nil {

    }
    else {
        println("\(newTitle)")
        println("\(newBody)")
        println("\(selectedNoteIndex)")
        let realTitle: String = newTitle
        let realBody: String = newBody
        let realIndex: Int = selectedNoteIndex
        noteTitles[realIndex] = realTitle
        noteBodies[realIndex] = realBody
    }
```

My logs show this:

```
New Note Title
This is what lies within
nil
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

and I get

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_i385_INVOP,subcode=0x0)
```

on the line

```
let realIndex: Int = selectedNoteIndex
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: BTW Swift is a type inferred language. Give it a try !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I was getting these errors is because while segueing back to the main view, I was not using the proper unwind segue, and instead using another show segue, which erased all data that had previously been within the view controller. By creating a unwind segue, I was able to keep the values before the segue to the detail view and prevent the error.

Answer (score 1):

`var varName: Type!` declares an *implicitly unwrapped optional*.

It means that it will be automatically unwrapped when accessing the value with `varName`, i.e. without using `varName!`.

Thus, accessing the implicitly unwrapped optional `selectedNoteIndex` with `let realIndex: Int = selectedNoteIndex` when its value is actually `nil` results in the error you got.

---

Apple's Swift Guide states that:

> Implicitly unwrapped optionals should not be used when there is a
>   possibility of a variable becoming nil at a later point. Always use a
>   normal optional type if you need to check for a nil value during the
>   lifetime of a variable.

Answer (score -1):

Because you did not assign value for `selectedNoteIndex` so it shows nil. First, you have to check whether its not nil value.

```
if let selectedNoteIndex = realIndex{
    let realIndex: Int = selectedNoteIndex
}
```

Comment: That's not how optional binding is used - try `if let realIndex = selectedNoteIndex { ... }`