# Swift Array Sorting Error when sorting by Date

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

My problem is that I can't sort one of my arrays in swift by date. The array is filled with AnyObjects. This is currently my code to sort the array:

```
sort(postsArray, {(NSDateFormatter($0 as AnyObject?).valueForKey("date")!).timeIntervalSinceNow > (NSDateFormatter($1 as AnyObject?).valueForKey("date")!).timeIntervalSinceNow})
```

This code works when I hardcode it to find the value of the date of the first element, but doesn't work in the sorting process. The error it gives me is, "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value." Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28359250/2108547

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your array is filled with AnyObjects you need to cast your AnyObject to NSDate to sort it. You can use NSDate method compare() as follow:

```
let date1 = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(1000)
let date2 = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(-1000)
let date3 = NSDate()

let postsArray:[AnyObject] = [date1,date2,date3]

let postsSorted = postsArray.sorted{($0 as! NSDate).compare($1 as! NSDate) == .OrderedAscending}

postsSorted  // ["May 23, 2015, 7:35 PM", "May 23, 2015, 7:51 PM", "May 23, 2015, 8:08 PM"]
```

If your array contains strings you can create an extension to convert it to NSDate as follow:

```
extension String{
    var toDate:NSDate {
        let df = NSDateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:SS zzz"
        return df.dateFromString(self)!
    }
}


let postsArray:[AnyObject] = ["Wed, 27 May 2015 15:12:09 EDT","Fri, 22 May 2015 15:12:09 EDT","Tue, 19 May 2015 15:12:09 EDT"]

postsArray[0] as! String

let postsSorted = postsArray.sorted { ($0 as! String).toDate.compare(($1 as! String).toDate) == .OrderedAscending}

postsSorted  // "Tue, 19 May 2015 15:12:09 EDT", "Fri, 22 May 2015 15:12:09 EDT", "Wed, 27 May 2015 15:12:09 EDT"]
```

Comment: no its filled with objects that are of the class any object

Comment: I asked if all objects are Dates, how would you sort non dates?

Comment: the objects all contain a property called date with a String formatted like "Sat, 23 May 2015 15:12:09 EDT." thats why I go the valueForKey("dates")